# Can one do interfaces in Javascript like C++? Goal is to resolve mutual dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We keep encountering circular dependencies.  We are using requirejs to manage our modules.  We are just beginning to use webpack, which may help.

I moved to Javascript from the C++ world.  In the C++ world, if object A depended on object B, and object B depended on object A, we would refer to the sister object, but not incorporate it.

```
class A {
    B* b;  // This indicates that b is a reference to, not a copy of, B.
}

class B {
    A* a;
}
```

If we said the following, our compilation (linking?) would stop immediately because B wasn't defined completed as the time we tried to incorporate it into A.

```
class A { 
    B a;
}

class B {
    A a;
}
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in Javascript?  Refer to the calling protocol of an object, without referring to its implementation?

---

Here's a Javascript version of the same question.

```
// A.js:
define(['B'], function(B) { ... });

// B.js
define(['A'], function(A) { ... });
```

That fails.

But this would work, if it can be done:

```
// A.js
define(['refB'], function(refB) { ... }); 

// B.js
define(['refA'], function(refA) { ... });
```

refB is an object that isn't B, but that you can use to call functions / access data in B.

Comment: Javascript before ES6 only loosely had the concept of "classes". There is no such static linking which would restrict you from doing this. Javascript is also duck typed, so you wouldnt refer to `A` or `B` they'd all just be objects - and if they happen to quack like an `A` then its an `A`.

Comment: There is no interfaces implementation in javascript but maybe you could have a look at mixins

Comment: Here's a Javascript version of the same question.  In A.js:  define(['B'], function(B) { ... });  In B.js:  define(['A'], function(A) { ... });  That fails.  But this would work, if it can be done:  In A.js:  define(['refB'], function(refB) { ... });  In B.js:  define(['refA'], function(refA) { ... });  refB is an object that isn't B, but that you can use to call functions / access data in B.

Comment: Boy, even I can't read that.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Edit the question with more code, reading code in a comment is impossible.

Comment: I put the same javascript example into the main question.  Thanks to Jamiec for pointing out how one achieves a formatted comment.